# DWG Import: How to resolve vector <t> too long?

Tags: dwg

I'm attempting to import a schematic layout however in the DWG/DXF import menu, I get the  "vector  too long" error message for ~1400 entities. It's my first time importing a DWG file, so I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: are you using AutoCAD?

Comment: No. I've been given a mass of files to play with and one of them was an autocad drawing file. I'm assuming I can add it as a layer and can compare with the other polygon layers.

Comment: What GIS Software are you using?